# Script Deletes Rows that do not match the criteria.

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script which I have set up to delete a row in a google spreadsheet if column 17 contains 'dead'. So far the script has deleted these rows but also takes a few rows that don't meet the criteria with it. I assumed this was due to the sheet taking a while to load and the script trying to delete a row that has already been deleted. I added a 'sleep' time of 20 seconds to the script to allow for delayed load times, however this has not helped.

```js
function Delete() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Enquiry Log'); 
  var values = s.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var row in values)
    if (values[row][17] == 'DEAD')
      s.deleteRow(parseInt(row)+1);
  Utilities.sleep(20000);
};
```

Any ideas on why the script still deletes rows that don't match the criteria?

Comment: It's because every time one row is deleted, all the rows underneath are now shifted up one.  Your code either needs to account for every row deleted and add that to the row number to be deleted, or delete from the bottom up.  And I wouldn't use `for (var row in values)` to loop through an array in JavaScript.  Use `for (var i=0,L=values.length;i<L;i++)`

Comment: That's brill, thanks so much :)